# How to kill a cocos2d scene directly without replacing scene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I'm starting the game with a UIViewController in this way:

```
navController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
```

and when you push the game button the game start the scene in this way:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:gameScene];
```

ok, now when I want to quit I just replace the UIViewController (because I did the menu with UIKit and the game with cocos2d) with the starting view controller to do the animation I want, it works fine... but obviously the old running scene still remains in memory, it is not deallocated in any way, I need to remove the scene and make the app as it was at the first running.

The replaceScene didn't work, I just need to stop the running scene and make everything as it was when the app started running, from the [CCDirector sharedDirector] direcly, how can I do it? popScene won't work too.

Comment: load an empty scene and call director's stopAnimation

Comment: I can't load an empty scene, I need to switch between the current scene and the UIViewController (which is working), I've tried to stopAnimation and to call [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]; the scene is ended but when I call another game scene nothing happens

Comment: you have to call startAnimation then. Isn't your uiviewcontroller fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the CCDirector from the application.

the director is a simple UIViewController so, you can call

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] removeFromParentViewController];
```

and after call the `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];` to remove the singlenton instance

Comment: I have some games, not just one, and when I quit one I'm switching the scene between the UIViewController and the scene, if I do what you've said, when I start another game I receive the "Do not initialize the TextureCache before the Director" crash message

Comment: ok, try release the TextureCache before call the "end" method of the Director... [CCTextureCache purgeSharedTextureCache];

Comment: Nothing seems to work, I have a simpler question, if you have 2 scenes of 2 games, which would you start in the appDelegate? and how you're supposed to replace them after? whatever I do seems to be wrong, if I put a scene, let's say "game 1 scene" in the appDelegate, and then I press the "game 1 button", it is shown properly. 

But if I put the "game 1 scene" in the appDelegate and I press the "game 2 button" I got the -OpenGL error 0x050- and then the scene starts (with "damaged" animation). I tried with a "intro scene" but the result is that I've always an error and the badly swap animation

Comment: why you not use the same instance of cocos for all games, only you need is change the scene, scene 1 for the game 1 and scene 2 for the game 2